# Change elevation shadow color in API 27 or previous

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, mobile, material-design

I need to change the shadow color of views, especially MaterialCardView. Is there anyway to do it natively? Or maybe a lib that has good "drawing performance"?
I tried View#setOutlineAmbientShadowColor(int color) and View#setOutlineSpotShadowColor(int color) but unfortunately I can´t use API 28 things in the project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add below the code in styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/century_gothic</item>
    <item name="android:ambientShadowAlpha">1</item>
    <item name="android:spotShadowAlpha">1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: didn't work for me bro. I tried exactly as you said but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom view that solved my problem. You can put your views inside the ShadowView, that is my custom view, and then you can control the shadow.

You can use the view by adding my lib https://github.com/bauermateus/shadow-view . There is a explanation.

it´s similar to:

```
<com.mbs.shadow_view.ShadowView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:radius="12dp"
    app:shadowAlpha="200"
    app:shadowColor="#FF5722"
    app:shadowPosition="center"
    app:shadowSpread="3"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@color/black"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:strokeColor="#FF5722"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp" />

</com.mbs.shadow_view.ShadowView>
```

will result in this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oR4E.png)